# helm chart template: if value does not exist, defaults to true

Tags: templates, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I am trying to declare that a block of code in a helm template should be present if a variable is true OR does not exist (ie, the default of the var is true). The following works:

```
    {{- if or .Values.livenessProbe (not (hasKey .Values "livenessProbe")) }}
    ...
    {{- end }}
```

This seems rather complex, is there something simpler? I tried with `default` function in a few ways but they all result in ignoring the value (present or not, true or false, the block always gets rendered):

```
    {{- if (default true .Values.livenessProbe) }}
    ...
    {{- end }}
```

Answer (score 13):

See https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#default for an explanation of why `default` does not work as expected: boolean false is considered "empty", so when value is false the default returns the default value ie ignores the actual value!

I also found https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3308, which shows that many people get tripped by this. Looking at other solutions in that issue, I feel mine (posted as part of the question) is actually simplest, rather unfortunate. Pattern is like this:

```
{{- if or .Values.myVar (not (hasKey .Values "myVar")) }}
...
{{- end }}
```

which basically says "render the block if the value is true, OR if the value is false because the key does not exist".

Answer (score 3):

simpler solution I got was to do it like this

```
list nil true | has .Values.value
```

Answer (score 2):

Got another clean solution using [ne](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#ne) (not-equal)

```yaml
valuekey: {{ ne .Values.value false }}
```

---

| `value` | true | false | null or empty | *not spesified* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `valuekey` | true | false | true | true |

Answer (score 0):

Use false value in double quotes so default in helm will consider it as string  instead of null. Following setting worked for me.

```
valuekey: "false"
```