# Usage of variables in Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I'm using a Helm chart and I was wondering how I can define a value by default. In my case, I wanna define a date when it isn't defined in values.yaml and I have the following code:

```
{{- if ne .Value.persistence.home.restoreBackup.date "" }}
{{- $bkDate := .Value.persistence.home.restoreBackup.date }}
{{- else }}
{{- $bkDate := "2022-01-01" }}
{{- end }}
```

I wanna set **$bkDate** to an specific date if it is not defined in `.Value.persistence.home.restoreBackup.date` but when I try to print **$bkDate** it is empty.

Do you know what is wrong here?

Comment: This might be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66265193/helm-chart-template-if-value-does-not-exist-defaults-to-true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Go `text/template` documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) notes (under "Variables"):

> A variable's scope extends to the "end" action of the control structure ("if", "with", or "range") in which it is declared....

This essentially means you can't define a variable inside an `if` block and have it visible outside the block.

For what you want to do, the [Helm `default` function](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#default) provides a straightforward workaround.  You can unconditionally define the variable, but its value is the Helm value or else some default if that's not defined.

```
{{- $bkDate := .Value.persistence.home.restoreBackup.date | default "2022-01-01" -}}
```

(Note that a couple of things other than empty-string are "false" for purposes of `default`, including "unset", `nil`, and empty-list, but practically this won't matter to you.)

If you need more complex logic than this then the [`ternary`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#ternary) function could meet your needs `{{- $var := $someCondition | ternary "trueValue" "falseValue" -}}` but this leads to hard-to-read expressions, and it might be better to refactor to avoid this.

Comment: It works for me! I had to delete the final "-" but after that it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
{{- if ((.Value.persistence.home.restoreBackup).date) }}
{{- $bkDate := .Value.persistence.home.restoreBackup.date }}
{{- else }}
{{- $bkDate := "2022-01-01" }}
{{- end }}
```

You can check the with option : https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#modifying-scope-using-with

```
{{ with PIPELINE }}
  # restricted scope
{{ end }}
```