# Why do I get an "undefined variable" error for a variable defined inside an `if` block?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

When I try to install a Helm chart with a template file:

```yaml
{{ if eq .Release.Namespace "fedx-app-1100" }}{{ $nodePort := 30106 }}{{ end }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }} 
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
    nodePort: {{ $nodePort }}
```

It produces an error:

```
Error: parse error at (fedx-install/templates/mysql.yaml:21): undefined variable "$nodePort"
```

What causes this error?  How can I restructure the template file to avoid it?

Comment: Error: parse error at (fedx-install/templates/mysql.yaml:21): undefined variable "$nodePort"

Comment: This is very similar to [Usage of variables in Helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72174577/usage-of-variables-in-helm): the variable definition's scope is only the containing `if` block.  In that question I suggest using the `default` function to provide a default without introducing a block scope.  Does that approach help?  Or are you trying to suppress this Service entirely if the namespace is different from what's expected?

Answer (score 1):

Just try this

```
{{ if eq .Release.Namespace "fedx-app-1100" }}{{ $nodePort := 30106 }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }} 
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
    nodePort: {{ $nodePort }}
{{ end }}
```